# layer when tap button

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, layer

I have this code in which I leave the "ColorCell" class to my cell, after which I want to click on a button of my collectio, I created ul layes around (only the selected one) to get an idea and know which premo. the code works, debugging within the function but not executing it, it only runs the tapColor

```
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: ColorCell.cellId, for: indexPath) as! ColorCell
        if cell.isSelected {
            cell.locationImage.layer.borderWidth = 1
            cell.locationImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            self.delegate?.tapColor(colorRound: datasource[indexPath.item].color)
        }
    }
    class ColorCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    static let reuseIdentifier = "TextColorRoundCell_RID"
    static let cellId = "ImageSliderCell__"
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViews()
    }
    var cellID: String?
    var locationImage = UIImageView().then{
        $0.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
        $0.layer.cornerRadius = (((UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width/8)*0.8)/2)
//        $0.layer.borderWidth = 1
//        $0.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    }

    func setupViews(){
        self.addSubview(self.locationImage)
        self.locationImage.activate([
            locationImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.8),
            locationImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.locationImage.widthAnchor),
            locationImage.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
            locationImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
            ])
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgNws.jpg)

Comment: "to get an idea and know which premo." Did you use the google translator? hahahahah
Anyway if you want to give a specific function to a button inside a cell, you should take the button and add to it a target like "button.addTarget(self, #selector(yourFunction:), sender: nil)"

Right now when you tap on a cell it triggers the function "didSelectItemAt" and only the function tapColor get called

Comment: @FrancescoDestino ok. so should I create a function like I did with tapColor? and simply declare to create the layer? in this way, however, does not create it to all the buttons?

Comment: I'm trying to understand your problem: you want that the button inside your cell could execute an action right?! Or maybe you're talking about buttons as your cells?

Comment: @FrancescoDestino ho una 10 di button all’interno della collection, che dichiaro con un unico arrey, vorrei che quando premo su uno mi si crei un layer attorno. in modo che so che ho selezionato quello

Comment: Quindi a quanto ho capito non vengono eseguiti queste due righe
cell.locationImage.layer.borderWidth = 1
            cell.locationImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
Giusto?

Comment: @FrancescoDestino si esatto. io in pratica quando clicco su un button della Collection si attiva solo la funzione tapColor. che in pratica mi cambia il colore della label con il colore cliccato. io vorrei applicare un layer al colore cliccato in modo tale che l'utente abbia riferimento al colore selezionato. però nonostante passi di li non ottengo nulla.. solo il cambio colore della label

Comment: Prova a mettere un semplice collectionView.reloadData dopo che inserisci il bordo e vediamo cosa succede!
Se riesci fammi vedere uno screenshot anche della tua parte grafica cosi mi rendo conto di cosa stai facendo :)

Comment: @FrancescoDestino no ho provato adesso ma esegue solo la funzione. dei due layer non vedo nulla. ho inserito la foto .

Comment: Allora prova a cambiare quelle due linee cosi

cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

E quando prendi la cella usa questa funzione

collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! ColorCell

Comment: @FrancescoDestino sto provano cos' ma niente...

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: ColorCell.cellId, for: indexPath) as! ColorCell
        if cell.isSelected {
            cell.layer.borderWidth = 1
            cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            self.delegate?.tapColor(colorRound: datasource[indexPath.item].color)
            collectionView.reloadData()
        }

Comment: Non usare dequeueReusableCell ma cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)

Comment: @FrancescoDestino Perfetto! Ora funziona, premo e mi crea il layer a quello selezionato. però ora devo chiederti una cosa.. perchè se ne clicco 2 o più avrò 4 layer.. come faccio a disattivare quelli?

Comment: Eh perché tu setti il layer con un colore ma non gli dici mai di toglierlo; quindi rimarrà per sempre! Ora da fare quello che vuoi se ho capito bene

Comment: @FrancescoDestino si esatto, adesso sto provando nella stessa funziona ma non sembrerebbe funzionare..

Comment: Prova ad aggiungere quel ciclo for che ti ho messo nella risposta :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: ColorCell.cellId, for: indexPath) as! ColorCell
    if cell.isSelected {
        cell.locationImage.layer.borderWidth = 1
        cell.locationImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        self.delegate?.tapColor(colorRound: datasource[indexPath.item].color)
    }



    for singleCell in collectionView.visibleCells {
        if singleCell != cell {
            singleCell.layer.borderWidth = 0
            singleCell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear
        }
    }
    collectionView.reloadData() 
}
```

Prova cosi, ci sarebbero un sacco di modi per risolvere questo problema

**EDIT 2**

```
class ColorCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    //Qui dentro inserisci tutti i componenti della cella

    //var label: UILabel
    //var image: UIImage etc..

    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet{
            if isSelected {
            //QUI cambi i colori degli elementi
            } else {
            //QUI resetti i colori come erano all'inizio
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Funziona!! alla grande, l'unica cosa, ho tolto il reloadData... il realtà basta così. con il reload non so perché ma veniva selezionato il coloro dopo :) Grazie mille ancora !!

Comment: Oh allora devo aver sbagliato io con quel comando :)
Comunque sono contento di averti aiutato ;)

Comment: Possibile perchè viene richiamato già nel viewDidLoad? :) comunque grazie davvero 
tra l'altro sono di Torino anche io ahah

Comment: Nono perché il reloadData dovrebbe essere utilizzato per altro e non per quello

Comment: stavo cercando di ripetere la stessa cosa per la Collection sotto al colore, per i font. cliccando dovrei visualizzare la scritta in bianco(per quella selezionata) però me la tiene in memoria

Comment: func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! FontCell
        if cell.isSelected {
            cell.array.textColor = UIColor.white
            self.delegate?.tapFont(fontRound: datasource[indexPath.item])
        }
        
        for singleCell in collectionView.visibleCells {
            if singleCell != cell {
                
                cell.array.textColor = UIColor.red
            }
        }
    }

Comment: stesso codice.. ma devo cambiare il colore della label nella cella.

Comment: Ti consiglierei di creare una funzione apposita nella cella che ti consente di modificare tutti gli elementi quando la cella é selezionata e una funzione per resettare i componenti! In modo tale da richiamare queste due funzioni nella didSelect, e cambiare i colori nelle funzioni interne

Comment: Guarda qualche tutorial su come creare delle celle di tipo custom e come utilizzarle al meglio :)